# Office Add-In deployed through O365 Admin Center Appears in Excel Ribbon but can´t be open

Tags: excel, deployment, office-js, office-js-helpers

I have deployed an Office Add-in and uploaded through the O365 Admin Center The Add-In appears in the Excel Ribbon but can use it as a message appears “We could not open the Add-In from LocalHost.

Should I modify anything in the Manifest File?

The Add-In was created with Yeoman and it´s addressed to “LocalHost:3000”.

It´s just a template (taskpane example)

Many thanks in advance!!! 
Regards, 
José.

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is only used to host the add-in during development. If you have deployed the add-in with [Centralized Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment), then you should be hosting the add-in on a web server or cloud account. In that case, the URLs in the manifest should be changed to the domain that is hosting the add-in.

Comment: Thanks Rick,As I come from VBA I did not do that process never before. By cloud account do you mean OneDrive or similar? Do you have any example to host in a web server? Many thanks

Comment: This article is all we have: [Host an add-in on Microsoft Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/host-an-office-add-in-on-microsoft-azure) But there are many frameworks and web servers you can use. Hosting the web app in an Office add-in is the same as hosting any web app. It seems that you might have skipped some of the basic documentation. Please start with [Start Here! A guide for beginners making Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/learning-path-beginner).

Comment: (1/2) If I have skipped any step it has been due to it is difficult for VBA users to understand the documentation. 99% of VBA users have never heard about Azure or Web Apps hosted in servers, O365 admin center and so on. With a lot of difficulty I got a web adddin running in a local server using IIS and a shared folder, but now I have to investigate how to do it to host it in a web server which brings to me many more hours to investigate. As me there will be many other VBA programmers facing these problems soon as they will want to learn.

Comment: (2/2) I recommend you to include this process in the next learning path chapter if you desire VBA users using this technology in the future. Remember how easy is with VBA create a macro and run it. Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: Since you are working with Excel, you should also consider whether Office Scripts can meet your needs. They are probably closer to VBA macros: [Office Scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/scripts/).

Comment: I prefer Script Lab more than Office Scripts. I am trying to understand Azure to host AddIns. It´s good to know new things.